# Sonatype LDAP users unable to login

Tags: ldap, sonatype

Nexus Sonatype is configured to LDAP server and users are assigned belongs to a group. Now none of those LDAP users are able to login.

I logged into local admin user account into Sonatype and none of those users are showing up on users tab.

Are those users deleted?

If I have to add them again, please let me know how to add new users using LDAP.

Comment: I can't diagnose this based on the information you've given.  I'd suggest contacting us at Sonatype support, https://support.sonatype.com

Comment: never mind it found the issue ldap server connecting to have some connecting problem changed to another server it worked Thanks

Comment: Have had the same problem for ages.  It's an intermittent fault that I've never got to the bottom of.  You can log in as a local admin user and the LDAP settings all check out fine.  Restarting Nexus sometimes solves the problem temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

logged in using local admin, checked on security > ldap configurations changed another server name it worked and all configured users backup. Now able to login